# Finding rational of zeros and then writing in factored form

Tags: polynomials, factoring

For an assignment in my Algebra 2 class we have to find the rational zeros of the equation then write it in factored form.

I am a little lost and don't really get it

Equation:

> $h(x)=x^3-5x^2+2x+8$

I have tried first getting the rational zeros and got

> $1, 2, 4, 8$

Then using synthetic substition

> $2$ | $1$ $-5$ $2$ $8$
>
> ____2 -6 -8____

From that i got

> $1x^3$ $-3$ $-4$ and finally $0$

Then wrote it into a function

> $h(x)=(x-2)(x^2-3x-4x)$

Which i don't know if it is correct, i also don't know what they mean by factor it

It would be helpful if you could show all you steps so i can actaully learn how to do it myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have factorised it correctly. We have $h (2)=0$ so one of the roots is 2. Also the quadratic should be $x^2-3x-4$.

Comment: One mistake: it's $x^2-3x-4$, not $x^2-3x-4x = x^2-7x$.

Comment: A polynomial of degree 3 with 4 roots ? Is that what you mean when getting the zeros ?

Comment: @Xxdzs sorry meant rational zeros

Comment: But by zero, you mean a value such that h(v) = 0 ??
Because h(1) = 1 - 5 + 2 + 8 = 6 != 0
Not sure to follow you

Comment: @Xxdzs from what I understand we have to make (x^3-5x^2) and (2x+8) both equal zero

Comment: No, we only want h(x) to be 0.
As Rohan mentionned, whenever you find a root, you can factorise by (X-r)

Comment: But where did the ___2 -6 -8___ came from ?

Comment: @Xxdzs  We have to use Synthetic substitution and that's where it's from

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything right so far! Just factor the quadratic $x^2-3x-4$ to completely factor $x^3-5x^2+2x+8$.

---

Although, you *could* do it this way:
$$\begin{align*} & x^3-5x^2+2x+8\\ & =x^3-4x^2-x^2+2x+8\\ & =x^2(x-4)-(x-4)(x+2)\\ & =(x-4)(x^2-x-2)\\ & =(x-4)(x-2)(x+1)\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

But not many people might've seen the first step...